# What type of subjective probability is adopted by Quine?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-physics, probability, quine

I am wondering what type of subjective probability is adopted by Quine. Is Quine sympathetic towards de Finetti's probability or Bayes'ones?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Quine's perspective on probability?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55708/what-is-quines-perspective-on-probability)

Comment: Thanks @Conifold I am still unsure about whether his view is a more Bayesian one or personalist (like de Finetti)